# trying to insert php into img src attribute to display featured image on custom post archive page in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

The image is set to return a URL in the Custom Fields Plugin however it is just coming up with img src Unknown, everything else works on the page except this... code is as follows: Thanks in advance for any help!

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'artists',
  );
  $query = new WP_Query( $args );

 ?>
  <section class="row artists">
    <?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
        <a href="<?php if( get_post_field('artist_website') ) { ?>
           <?php echo $artist_website; ?>
         <?php } else { the_permalink(); } ?>">
          <img src="<?php get_post_field('artist_feature_image'); ?>" alt="<?php echo the_title() ; ?>">
          <p><?php echo the_title() ;?></p>
        </a>
      </div>

    <?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

  </section>



<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that **`get_post_field('artist_feature_image')`** only return the image.

You need to display it with "echo"

```
<img src="<?php echo get_post_field('artist_feature_image'); ?>" />
```

And don't do **`echo the_title() ;`**, because `the_title()` is already doing an echo on `get_the_title();`

```
function the_title() {
 echo get_the_title();
}
```

So if you want to display it you just have to do: **`the_title();`**

Comment: Thank you! I had missed that, however even with the echo it now just returns an integer like so....     <img src = "48" ....

Comment: What is the plugin you are using?

Comment: It's may be because your field doesn't return the image itself but the image id ?

Comment: I am using Advanced Custom Fields and Custom Post Type UI. In ACF I have the image field set to return the image URL not the image ID which is what is confusing me :S

Comment: Sorted - had to use get_field instead of get_post_field!

Comment: Yes, i was pretty sure that you were using acf ^^. Use get_field() of course